# Can't subtract hours from time data because of data type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to subtract 12 hours from my time data based on certain conditions and it's not working.
My data looks like this:

```
 StartTime        EndTime       Hours
12:00:00         00:30:00        5.5       
12:00:00         00:30:00       -4.5
13:00:00         01:20:00       -6.5
12:30:00         04:06:00       -12.1
12:30:00         04:06:00       -12.1
12:30:00         04:06:00       -12.1
```

I want to flip AM to PM (e.g. - or + 12 hours) in EndTime if "Hours" is negative and not -12.1. So I did this:

```
if df[df["Hour"] < 0].all().all()  and df["Hours"].all().all() != -12.1:
    df["EndTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["EndTime"]) - timedelta(hours=12)
```

But there's no change in my data. The current data type of EndTime and StartTime is object so I tried to change it from object to datetime but got this error.
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

I tired these codes (not at the same time) but none of them worked.

```
df['Hours'] = df['Hours'].astype('datetime64')
df['Hours'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hours']).dt.time
df['Hours'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hours']).dt.floor('d')
```

I'm not sure if my code which subtracts 12 hours because data type of my time values or I chose a wrong option for my if statement. For example, I'm not sure I can use all().all() in this case.

Comment: In the `if` statement, there is `Hour` instead of `Hours`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: no that wasn't a case. It still didn't work

Comment: I posted an answer about possible workarounds to add a `timedelta` to `time`. I don't know how to apply these in `pandas` but maybe it will be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Objects of the `time` class do not support the adding/subtracting arithmetics, so you have to somehow work around using `datetime` objects:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

>>> end_time = time(1, 20, 0)

>>> end_datetime = datetime.combine(date(2020, 1, 1), end_time)
>>> new_datetime = end_datetime + timedelta(hours=12)

>>> new_end_time = new_datetime.time()
>>> new_end_time
datetime.time(13, 20)
```

Or maybe just simply replace the hour in the `time` object:

```py
>>> end_time = time(1, 20, 0)

>>> new_hour = (end_time.hour + 12) % 24
>>> new_end_time = end_time.replace(hour=new_hour)

>>> new_end_time
datetime.time(13, 20)
```